# Email from contact form error: Method Not Allowed (POST) 405

Tags: python, html, django

I'm creating a Contact page on my portfolio site which when the user fills out and submits will automatically send it as an email to my personal email account. But when I hit Submit I get "Method Not Allowed (POST):/contact/" in my terminal, "HTTP ERROR 405" in my browser and no email in my account.

My HTML:

```
 <form action="" method="POST">

  {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col">
      <input name="f-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input name="s-name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email-input" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="name@mail.com" required>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">I Wont Share Your Email!</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <textarea name="e-message" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="your message..." required></textarea>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>

</form>
```

My views.py:

```
class ContactView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'contact.html'

     def send_message(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            message = request.POST['f-name', 's-name', 'email', 'e-message']
            send_mail('Contact Form', message,['email@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False)

            return render(request, 'thanks.html')
```

My project urls.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path, include
 from django.contrib.auth import views
 from blog import views

 urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('projects/', views.ProjectView.as_view(), name='projects'),
    path('blog/', views.BlogView.as_view(), name='blog'),
    path('contact/', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('thanks/', views.ThanksView.as_view(), name='thanks'),
```

My application urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views


app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.AboutView.as_view(), name='about'),
    url(r'^projects/$', views.ProjectView.as_view(), name='projects'),
    url(r'^blog/$', views.BlogView.as_view(), name='blog'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.ContactView.as_view(), name='contact'),
    url(r'^thanks/$', views.ThanksView.as_view(), name='thanks'),
```

Iv been searching for similar answers for a few hours and anything similar  hasnt helped so far Maybe I should re build my form in Django forms? I dont want to risk going too far changing too much and breaking my site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does not support post method on template view implicitly. You have to define post method yourself in template view like this

```
class ContactView(TemplateView):
     template_name = 'contact.html'

     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message = request.POST['e-message']
        send_mail('Contact Form', message,['email@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)

        return render(request, 'thanks.html')
```

The rest will be handled automatically

Comment: I changed as you said but from there I get a new error. MultiValueDictKeyError at /contact/ ..('f-name', 's-name', 'email', 'e-message')

Comment: Okay I just copied code from question. See my edit.

Comment: Okay I think we're close I removed all the other items from the list so I just have the ['e-message'] now i'm getting "SMTPAuthenticationError at /contact/" "Application-specific password required." I have put my correct password in my settings.py file im using my regular gmail address as my EMAIL_HOST_USER, TLS = True ans SSL = False. Should I use a different EMAIL_HOST instead of the using the same as Im sending too?

Comment: I has 2 factor authentication on, I created an app password on my Gmail account and all is working good now! Thanks so much!